# nested loop async call in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, async-await

I have this array of objects

```js
const items = [
  {
    quantity: '2',
    name: 'john',
    type: 'https://api/event/1',
  },
  {
    quantity: '3',
    name: 'jane',
    type: 'https://api/event/2',
  }
]
```

for each object in the array, I need to call the API `n` number of times depending on the object `quantity` value. Calling the API will basically generate a unique link. I know this is not the best for performance but this is a small app and we'd be making between 3-5 api calls in the worst case scenario, usually 1 tbh. In this case, I have 2 objects in the array, the first has 2 API calls and the second has 3 API calls. Every time I call the API I want to save the result (unique link) in an array so that I can email them to the customer who bought them.

This is what I have tried so far but it hasn't worked:

```js
  const promises = []
  const getLinks = async (arr) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].quantity; j++) {
        const getLink = (owner) => {
          axios.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.call'
          })
         .then(function (response) {              
            const promise = response.data.url
            promises.push(promise)
          })
         .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
      }
    }
    const links = await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log('links:', links)  // === [] this is always empty ===
  }

getLinks(items)
```

One thing I learned is that await cannot be and will slow down the code drastically inside loops

I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: getLink is never called?

Comment: If you want to increase the requests rate, then take care that you don't get blocked by the server. Is there any limitation there?

Comment: Hey I posted an answer, let me know if it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

- `getLink` is never called in your code.
- Even, if it is called, when `Promise.all(promises)` runs, the `promises` array is still be empt because it is populated in the `then` callback which runs later
- You are pushing the `url` from the response to the array instead of pushing the actual promises returned by axios

```js
const promises = []

for (const o of items) {
  for (let i = 0; i < o.quantity; i++) {
    const promise = axios.request({ method: post, url: o.type })
    promises.push(promise)
  }
}

const responses = await Promise.all(promises)
const urls = responses.map(r => r.data.url)
```

Or,
you could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) get an array of all the promises returned by axios and use `Promise.all` on the resulting array

```js
const promises = items.flatMap(o => 
  Array.from({ length: o.quantity }, _ => axios.request({ method: post, url: o.type })
)

const responses = await Promise.all(promises)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit confused about how Promises work.

```
 /* THIS THING IS A PROMISE -> */ axios.request({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://api.call'
 })
 .then(function (response) {              
     const promise = response.data.url // <-THIS THING IS NOT A PROMISE
 })
```

The `Promise` is the value of `axios.request()`. Therefore if you want the promise you should do this:

```
const promise = axios.request();
```

The value inside the `.then()` is **NOT** a `Promise`!! It is the value returned by the promise:

```
 const promoise = axios.request({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://api.call'
 })
 .then(function (response) {              
     const result = response.data.url;
     return result;
 })
```

Therefore you have been pushing the completely wrong thing to your `promises` array! You have been pushing the URL string returned by your api call instead of the promises.

To get your code working correctly is extremely simple:

```
const getLinks = async (arr) => {
  let promises = []

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].quantity; j++) {
      const getLink = (owner) => {
        const promise = axios.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://api.call'
        })
       .then(function (response) {              
          return response.data.url
        })
       .catch(error => console.log(error))

        promises.push(promise)
      }
    }
  }
  const links = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log('links:', links)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Map methods return an array
const apiResponse = items.map(async(apiCall) => {
  // call an api here and store its result in a veriable 
  let returnedResult
  await axios.get(apiCall.type)
    .then(response => {
      //refactor the reponse to how you want to store it in the array
      returnedResult = response
    })
  return returnedResult
})

Promise.all(apiResponse)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    // sent an email here based on the response you get
  })
```

Comment: `return returnedResult` will always be undefined

Comment: It still won't work inside `map` callback

Comment: I tried it on my local and it worked as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Update your code like the following, I tested on my side and its working and easy

const axios = require("axios");

const items = [
  {
    quantity: "2",
    name: "users",
    type: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1",
  },
  {
    quantity: "3",
    name: "posts",
    type: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
  },
];

const allPromises = items
  .map((eachObject) => {
    const { type: url, quantity } = eachObject;
    const promiseArray = new Array(Number(quantity)).fill(axios.get(url));
    return promiseArray;
  })
  .reduce((prev, current) => {
    return [...prev, ...current];
  }, []);

Promise.all(allPromises)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res instanceof Array) {
      const result = res.map((each) => each.data);
      console.log("result is", result);
    } else {
      console.log("not an array");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => console.log("done!"));
```